# Replace numbers in a string with a string and the length of the number appended to it

Tags: python, regex

Basically I need to take a column in a dataframe which has a combination of chars and numbers, like 'XYZABC/123441 s   sdx' and such similar types

I need to remove all punctuation, single letter words, replace double spaces with single spaces, trim the string, and replace the numbers with "NUMB#" where '#' represents the length of the number. So '123441' here would be replaced with "NUMB6" and so on.

My current code is:

```
for x in df["colname"]:
    x = re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", " ", str(x))      #Removes all punctuations
    x = re.sub(r"\d+", "NUMB", str(x))       #Replaces digits with 'NUMB'
    x = re.sub(r"\b[a-zA-Z]\b", "", str(x))  #Removes all single characters
    x = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", str(x))          #Removes double spaces with single space
    x = x.strip().upper()                    #Trims the string
```

Now I did see a question on the website on how to replace substrings with their length:

```
re.sub(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b', lambda m: str(len(m.group(1))), s)
```

All I need to do here is replace the "([A-Z][a-z]*)" with '\d'. However, I don't know how to append the two together, the '.append' function doesn't work. This is probably an elementary thing, but I'm new to Python so I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `apply` like

```
def repl(x):
    return re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: "NUMB{}".format(len(m.group())), x)

 df['colname'] = df['colname'].apply(repl)
```

Or to use the same logic as in your code, replace `x = re.sub(r"\d+", "NUMB", str(x))` with

```
x = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: "NUMB{}".format(len(m.group())), x)
```

The `re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: "NUMB{}".format(len(m.group())), x)` will find any non-overlapping digit chunks and will replace them with `NUMB` and the length of the digit chunk.

Comment: It worked perfectly. For clarification, could you just explain the role the curly braces play in the quotes? I only know their use in creating dictionaries.

Comment: @Arjun In that case, it is a part of the format string where you may define placeholders that wil be replaced with the arguments provided to the `format` method. E.g. to get `Hello, world.` you may use `'{}, {}.'.format('Hello', 'world')`. Or `'{0}, {1}.'.format('Hello', 'world')`.