# How to replace all numbers (with letters/symbols attached, i.e. 43$) in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe of online comments related to the stock market.
Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'comment': ["I made $425",
                               "I got mine at 42c. per share", 
                               "Stocks saw a 12% increase"]})
```

I would like to replace all numbers in the dataframe (including the symbols and letters) with `NUMBER` to achieve:

```
"I made NUMBER",
"I got mine at NUMBER per share", 
"Stocks saw a NUMBER increase"
```

I found a close solution in a [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601330/replace-numbers-in-a-string-with-a-string-and-the-length-of-the-number-appended), but this solution still leaves me with the remaining letters and symbols.

```
def repl(x):
    return re.sub(r'\d+', lambda m: "NUMBER", x)

repl("I made 428c with a 52% increase")

>> I made NUMBERc with a NUMBER% increase
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think the main question is a precise definition of what to replace. Is it a series of digits with some arbitrary symbols and characters on each end? Or only some digits with a 'c' or  '$' on it? If any symbols are part of the 'number', what delimits these ? Probably whitespace and punctuation.   e.g.   "[a-zA-Z$%]*\d+[a-zA-Z$%]*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `[^\d\s]*\d\S*` regex to match any chunk of 0 or more chars other than digit and whitespace, then a digit, and then any amount of non-whitespace chars, and replace with `NUMBER` using a vectorized [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method.

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'comment': ["I made $425",
                               "I got mine at 42c. per share", 
                               "Stocks saw a 12% increase"]})
df['comment'] = df['comment'].str.replace(r'[^\s\d]*\d\S*', 'NUMBER')
df
# =>    id                         comment
# => 0   1                   I made NUMBER
# => 1   2  I got mine at NUMBER per share
# => 2   3    Stocks saw a NUMBER increase
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irkqB7/1), too. Details:

- `[^\d\s]*` - zero or more (`*`) occurrences of any char but a digit and whitespace (`[^\d\s]` is a negated character class)
- `\d` - any digit char
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, this is both informative and works!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import re

def repl(x):
    return re.sub(r'\S*\d+\S*', lambda m: "NUMBER", x)

print(repl("I made 428c with a 52% increase"))
```

Output:

```
I made NUMBER with a NUMBER increase
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is also great. I really should get more familiar with regex...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
def repl(l):
    s=""
    for i in l.split():
        if any([str(_) in i for _ in range(11)]):
            s+="Number"+' '
        else:
            s+=i+' '
    return s.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate it. I was hoping to avoid for loops as it is quite a large dataset.